# Is an interview part of EEA Family permit?

Tags: united-kingdom

my husband applied online for EEA Family Permit to come to UK, and handed in the  necessary documents at an Indian VFS office.
Does anyone have experience  with interviews as part of the application process?
Will they call either the EEA member or the applicant to clarify details?
Any help welcome.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There is no interview process for UK visa applications. The ECO may contact you or your EEA sponsor if there are minor aspects of your application requiring clarification. They can refuse outright without any prior contact if there are material deficiencies in the application sufficient for the ECO to conclude that you don't qualify for an EEA family permit.eg see https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/132606/refusal-of-eea-family-permit

Comment: In cases of suspected marriage (or partnership) of convenience, they are supposed to call the couple in for an interview before refusing the application.  Apparently this frequently does not happen.